# Snackbar like google io 2018 android

Tags: android, material-design, android-snackbar, material-components-android, googleio

How can I implement such a snackbar. To have it with round edges and show above fab and was not stretched across the width of the screen[image]

Answer (score 3):

Use the `Snackbar` in the [Material Components library](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android).
As default it has rounded corners.
Use the `setAnchorView` method to make a `Snackbar` appear above a specific view, in your case the fab button.

```
        Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(view, "...", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
        snackbar.setAnchorView(fab);
        snackbar.show();
```

Also you can customize the margin using the **`snackbarStyle`** attribute in the app theme.

```
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light">
    ....
    <item name="snackbarStyle">@style/MySnackbar</item>
  </style>
```

In the snackbar style use the **`android:layout_margin`** attribute.

```
  <style name="MySnackbar" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Snackbar">
    <item name="android:layout_margin">32dp</item>
  </style>
```

[image]

Comment: Which version of the Material Components library are you referring to. I'm using the latest [v1.1.0](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/releases/tag/1.1.0) and I'm still not getting rounded corners on my `Snackbar`.

Comment: Can one add green stroke to snackbar layout with this method?

Answer (score 1):

Try to adding this dependency.

```
implementation 'com.github.danimahardhika:cafebar:1.3.1'
```

Then can add Cafe Bar using this code.

```
CafeBar.builder(context)
.theme(CafeBarTheme.LIGHT)
.duration(CafeBar.Duration.MEDIUM)
.content(R.string.text)
.neutralText("Action")
//You can parse string color
.neutralColor(Color.parseColor("#EEFF41"))
//Or use color resource
.neutralColor(R.color.neutralText)
.show();
```

If you need more customization visit the documentation [here](https://github.com/danimahardhika/cafebar).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is part of Recently launched Material Components pack from Google .
Probably available on :-

```
com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-alpha3
```

Whereas Its still in alpha . So i am not quite sure whether you can use it in Production or not . I am attaching some links below to go through.

[Material Component Snack Bar](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/Snackbar.md)

[See all components list](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/tree/master/docs/components)

[Samples](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android)

Comment: It's not yet released as of now. The team still hasn't released a new release for a few days.